# How to deploy my site?

Tags: php, deployment

I am running PHPStorm, bought the Droplet on DigitalOcean.com and have the domain on 123.reg. Please help, I really need it I would really appreciate if you could talk to me in simple terms and guide me through the process, this is also my first site.

Comment: Please first try it yourself and come then back once you have issues and let us help you to find them

Comment: The best way to learn is by trial and error.

Comment: I have done. I am lost from the very star though  :(

Comment: I understand that but I cannot find the FTP Information etc

Answer (score 0):

DO has really good tutorials on their own website, please refer to those and ask specific questions here. Stackoverflow is a specific problem solving forum, not a 'fix my stuff' service.

[Guide to setup Apache and upload your site on a DigitalOcean droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use GIT. If you have to use FTP, there is tutorials for that to: https://anotherguru.me/how-to-install-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-14-04-on-digitalocean-droplet/

Comment: On my first Google search I literally found more than 10 step-by-step tutorials you just can't mess up. Just try them out.

Comment: Okay so I got the FTP stuff and everything but I am not sure how to host it with DO and link PHPStorm to 123 reg?